# when i wanted run blinking_led.py i got this error

Tags: opencv, python

**Hello everyone when i wanted to run blinking_led.py in python-opencv in windows 10 i faced this problem:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\LifeSTYLE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\TEST\blinking_led.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  #Import raspberry Pi GPIO library ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

After that i have tried to install RPi.GPIO i faced this problem too:

> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
>   failed with exit status 2
>   [error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ---
>
> Command "c:\users\lifestyle\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\LIFEST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8sq29xb7\rpi.gpio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\LIFEST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t7ye6d1q\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\LIFEST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8sq29xb7\rpi.gpio][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebk2E.jpg)

**If anyone could help please help! 
I could not find any useful suggestion.
Thanks beforehand!!!**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use module RPi.GPIO on Windows machine, because there is no GPIO interface.
It will only works with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: But I wanted to simulate it. Is it possible or I need some kind of special program

Comment: Yes. I found solution on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37780/94469